# Writer or PrintStream that expands tab chars into spaces at set tab stops

Tags: java, string-formatting

Id like a simple class lets call it Printer that supports richer formatting in addition to limiting decimal number places for doubles etc.

```
interface Printer {
   void print(CharSequence c);
}
```

Some interesting features i would like include:

- expanding tabs to the next multiple 8
- expanding tabs to a column after calling a callback which returns the column to jump towards.
- support for tab alignments. Any query for the next tab after column X would return jump to Y and right align.

Are there any FOSS libraries that contain features like this ?

- please do not tell me to write my own which i probably will.
- im not interested formatting numbers and other value types like dates.
- id rather the tab stops are not encoded as part of the "printing". Code should just print data then tabs and the result is nicely formatted.

Comment: This is not java, but here is a perl statement that translates tabs to spaces.  May give you and idea of what to do in java:  1 while $str =~ s/^([^\t]*)(\t+)/$1 . ' ' x (length($2) * 8 - length($1) % 8)/e;

Comment: Yeh i know how to do it its just tedious and id rather re-use than write :)